# Google Translate audio button missing

Tags: sound, google

My Google Translate does not have an audio button:
[image: My google translate]

I made sure that the Adobe Flash Plugin is activated but I still can't find it.

Now, I can't listen to Google Translate how to pronounce a word.

Is this an issue with Ubuntu? Or is this just an updated version of Google Translate?

Comment: It's not an issue for all Ubuntu, it works fine on mine. what version of Ubuntu do you have? Have you tried updating Firefox? Or have you tried a different browser like Chrome?

Comment: Does this happen only in private browsing mode (as in your screenshot) or always?

Comment: My firefox is 58.0.2.Even if I use normal browsing, the audio button won't show up

Comment: Adobe Flash Plugin isn't needed. I get the listen icon without it installed. In any case, please update your browser. Do you have any site blocker active, perhaps via your `hosts` file?

Comment: It's working fine on my machine so it's not an ubuntu issue.  I can use it on all my browsers chromium, firefox and opera.  I'm using 18.04.1 xfce.  Good luck in finding and answer.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1: For apt Firefox, install following plugin.

`sudo apt install browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash`

Solution 2: Install snap Firefox.  By default, sound button works.